# GNUPLOT heredoc; plot over xrange error

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a piecewise linear fit in (bash heredoc/script for) gnuplot. I tried this :

```
plot "datafile1" u 1:2:6:7:10:11 with xyerrorbars,\
     "datafile1" u 1:4:8:9:10:11 with xyerrorbars,\
     "datafile2" u 1:2:3 with xyerrorbars,\
     [xmin:xmax] f(x)
```

but it returns an invalid expression error. Any ideas why this fails?

note - `fit [xmin:xmax] f(x)` does not return any error messages (so I assume it works).

GNUPLOT 4.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allowed to specify a range at the beginning of the `plot` command. This range applies to all of the following, comma-delimited parts of this `plot` command. So you could use

```
plot [xmin:xmax] f(x),\
     "datafile1" u 1:2:6:7:10:11 with xyerrorbars
```

But that would apply the `[xmin:xmax]` range also to the `datafile1`. If you only want to limit the range of `f(x)`, you must define a function which is invalid (`1/0`) outside of the desired range:

```
plot "datafile1" u 1:2:6:7:10:11 with xyerrorbars,\
     "datafile1" u 1:4:8:9:10:11 with xyerrorbars,\
     "datafile2" u 1:2:3 with xyerrorbars,\
     (x > xmin && x < xmax) ? f(x) : 1/0
```

Note, that your original command will work in the upcoming gnuplot version 5.0

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to nag but, would this imply that this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110310/how-can-i-reduce-the-linear-fit-plot-to-a-certain-interval?rq=1) is misleading?

Comment: Yes, that answer is wrong, don't know why it was marked as accepted. The syntax show there works only in the development version (upcoming version 5.0). I'll leave a comment.